# laravel passport outh2 not working in the livehost

Tags: apache, oauth-2.0, hosting, laravel-passport, laravel-5.7

my project work very well in local server but when i publish it in live hosting everything work except  the oauth2 not work and give me [Route [login] not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noXcz.png)

i dont khnow were is the problem 
[my .htaccess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffidw.png)

[my Route api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CPgd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel redirect you to login route when API request doesn't authenticated, so add this line to `routes/web.php` file:

```
Route::post('login', [ 'as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'LoginController@do']);
```